# Xcode Swift add a value to a defined array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

What I'm looking to try to do is have another var attached to the array to store values in without having to make a 2D array.

```
var list: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
list.add("Apple")
list[0].color = red // Something like this
```

Any help in the right direction will be appreciated

Comment: You may create a custom class for the object stored in the array.

Comment: You have to create a model class and assign that as an element type to the array.

Comment: I assume an "apple" can have single colour property. Create Apple class with property as color. You can also use tuples, dictionaries.

Comment: D o.  N o t.  U s e.  N S M u t a b l e A r r a y.  I n.  S w i f t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that make array of custom class or struct.

```
struct Fruit {
    let name: String
    let color: String
}
```

Now make array of this struct and add object of this struct in it.

```
var fruits = [Fruit]()
fruits.append(Fruit(name: "Apple", color: "red"))
```

Now you can access object in a way you describe in your question.

```
print(fruits[0].name)  //Apple
print(fruits[0].color) //red
```

**Note:** In Swift use swift's type `Array` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.